# Is $f$ continuous at $0$?

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$
>
> $f(x) := \inf\{|nx − 1| : n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$

I found that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\big(\dfrac{1}{m+1}, \dfrac1m\big]$
and that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$

How can I say if $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ with these facts?

Comment: Assuming that by $inf$ you mean the floor function, your function is not continuous at zero, since $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0}f(x) \neq \lim\limits_{x\nearrow 0}f(x).

Comment: I think he meant $\inf$ not $in f$

Comment: edited, sorry..

Comment: if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ is true then $f$ is not continuous at $0$ because it is clear that $f(0)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to0} f(x) \neq0$ since $\forall\epsilon>0$, by the Archimedian property, we can find $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac2m<\epsilon$. But, we know that $\frac3{2m}<\frac2m$, and that $\inf|n\cdot\frac3{2m}-1|=\frac12$. In fact, this limit does not exist, since $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $f(\frac1n)=0$.

This proves that the function is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(0)=1$; if $m$ is a positive integer, then $m\frac{1}{m}-1=0$, so $f(1/m)=0$.